# currentPage not being assigned to zero on filter- AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-filter

I am using default Angular filter,

On change of text searchItems is called with search string:

```
<input type="text" ng-change="searchItems(searchquery)" ng-model="searchquery">
```

Inside the function, I update currentPage to 0 but it's not happening...

```
$scope.searchItems = function(searchString) {
            $scope.numberOfPages = 0;
            $scope.currentPage = 0;
            $scope.filterSearch = searchString;
            $scope.ObjectsAll = $scope.ObjectsAllMaster;

            //this is the filter
            $scope.ObjectsAll = $filter('filter')($scope.ObjectsAll, searchString)
            $scope.numberOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.ObjectsAll.length / $scope.pageSize);
            $scope.paginationShowHide = ($scope.numberOfPages > 1 ? true : false);
        }
```

The issue is that when I paginate to the 2nd or third page, and search in the text box, that only searches from that paginated page and does not update the currentPage to 0+1,
This causes not found, even if the item is there.

here is my pagination code.

```
<ul class="pagination pagination-sm"  ng-show="paginationShowHide">
        <li ng-class="prevPageDisabled(currentPage)"><a  ng-click="currentPage = currentPage - 1" href="javascript:void(0)"> &lt;&lt; </a></li>
        <li><a href="" style="pointer-events: none;cursor: default;">{{currentPage + 1}}/{{numberOfPages}}</a></li>
        <li ng-class="nextPageDisabled(currentPage)"><a ng-click="currentPage = currentPage + 1" href="javascript:void(0)"> &gt;&gt; </a></li>
    </ul>
```